# How do I Control the Pages the surveys are printed on?

Tags: javascript, css, printing, asp-classic

I am trying to print the results of a survey I send out (using a internal web base system).

The problem I am having is: 
I want each survey to print in a new page instead of having some start in the middle of the page.

All responses are between 1.5 and 3 pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these surveys are delivered as HTML and then printed from a web browser (your question is unclear here, so I'm guessing and going off the question tags), you can use [CSS Print Styles](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) to insert a [page break after](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) the last element in each survey:

```
page-break-after: always;
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, Thank you very much and sorry for not explaining what I needed better.